# Divisible group as the automorphism group of a algebraic variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory

Let $X$ a affine algebraic variety. Then $X$ can have infinite automorphism group, for example $X=\mathbb{A}^1$. Let $G$ be a divisible abelian group.
My question is about some condition in $G$ such that I can guarantee the existence of a algebraic variety $X$ such that $G$ is a subgroup of the isomorphism group of $X$.

More specifically, let $G_p$ the $p$-primary component of $G$. I want to construct $X$ with a rational point $P$ such that the orbit of $P$ by $G_p$ is rational over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. I want to know if there is some bibliography about this problem.

Comment: You're using "isomorphism" instead of "automorphism". The distinction between this two words is precious! Second, "has infinite automorphisms" is senseless. I don't guess if you mean "has an infinite automorphism group" or "has automorphisms of infinite order".

Comment: "Divisible group": are you assuming abelian? What is the $p$-primary component? the set of torsion elements whose order is a power of $p$?

Comment: I'm sorry I want to mean "automorphism". With respect to the second question in principle $G$ is abelian, and the $p$ primary component is the set of elements whose order is a power of $p$. I though in the problem. Let $\tau(G)$ the torsion group of $G$. Maybe if $G/\tau(G)= \mathbb{Q}^n$ then it quotient induce the space $\mathbb{A}^n$ and $\tau(G)$ be the galois group of the variety over $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Comment: I edited to fix wrong wording (I expected you would do so). Still I don't really understand what is the question, if there is any.

Comment: I'm sorry the question was about if there are some bibliography in it direction.

Comment: Yes but I mean the setting sounds vague. I guess you mean $X$ to be defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ (for "rational over $\mathbf{Z}_p$) to make sense. But also I don't even see why a $G_p$-orbit should be a subvariety. If you had an example in mind to illustrate this orbit stuff, it would be useful.

Comment: Let $X$ be a algebraic curve over $\mathbb{A}^1$. Suppose that $X=Spec(A)$. Since $A$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}[T]$ then the automorphism group of $A$ is a semidirect product between a finite group $G$ (the galois group of theextension) by the Automorphism group of $\mathbb{A}^1$. I expect that the last group have a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't precisely see the connection to your question. What is the divisible subgroup you are considering?